# Why would objects such as SurfFeatureDetector in C++ cause issues when wrapping into a C module using extern "C"?

Tags: php, c++, c, opencv, surf

I have written a small program in C++ and I'm simply trying to wrap it up in C as I'm working on a PHP extension in C. Generally things seems okay. The basics work, I can write a simple program in C++ and use `extern "C"` which works no problem.

But I'm also using OpenCV, and I seem to run into issues when I declare objects such as `SurfFeatureDetector`.

Here's my C extension Hello World starting point:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif
#include "php.h"
#include "php_framework.h"
#include "cvlink.h"

static function_entry framework_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(test, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

zend_module_entry framework_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    PHP_FRAMEWORK_EXTNAME,
    framework_functions,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    PHP_FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
#endif
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_FRAMEWORK
ZEND_GET_MODULE(framework)
#endif

PHP_FUNCTION(test)
{
    RETURN_STRING("Hello World", 1);
}
```

So here I am actually pulling in `cvlink.h` at the top, and the source file for that header looks like this:

```
#include "cvlink.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

extern "C" int process_two_images(const char* first_img_path, const char* second_img_path)
{
    Mat object_1 = imread(first_img_path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat object_2 = imread(second_img_path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    return 0;
}
```

This all works fine, so if I was to make a call to `process_two_images` in my C file it would work fine. But the next line after the `Mat object_1`... lines looks like this:

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(500);
```

Still, in terms of compilation everything is fine. But when I make a call to the `test` PHP function I have created here I get the undeclared function error.

Strange. It's probably something really obvious that I'm missing, but I don't know what.